# Simplest way to change numbers in localized format in an Xml file to english format

Tags: c#, xml

I have an application that generates a lengthy Xml output file which contains many many numbers in a non-english format, i.e. thousands delimiter is '.' and decimal delimiter is ','. However, to further process this Xml file, I need all the number values to be in english format (basically, swap the two delimiters). What is the simplest way to achieve this in C#?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I meant C#. Edited the question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution might be to take the number as a string and then parse it using the non-English locale into a double. This should convert the value (for example):

```
style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR");
if (Double.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number))
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", value, number);
else
   Console.WriteLine("Unable to convert '{0}'.", value);
```

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s27fasw.aspx)

Comment: This worked great! One caveat, though: Depending on the CurrentCulture, when assigning the new value you have to specify the desired NumberFormat, like e.g.: `valueAttribute.Value = localizedNumber.ToString(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US").NumberFormat); `.